# Display random files from a directory?

Tags: php, scandir

how to display random files from a directory? The code below only shows random 1 file, output should be 10 files.

```
<?php
$path = "/files";

$files = scandir($path);
shuffle($files);

for($i = 0; ($i < count($files)) && (!is_file($files[$i])); $i++);

echo $files[$i];
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP images from directory - Random order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666161/php-images-from-directory-random-order)

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i = 0; ($i < count($files)) && (!is_file($files[$i])); $i++);
                                                                 ^
```

Putting the semicolon there terminates the `for` loop statement, hence it doesn't actually do anything, and just loops until the condition is false. Remove the semi-colon to fix.

As a clearer example, take the following code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++);
    echo $i;
```

This will loop five times, as the `for` loop body statement is blank (due to the statement terminator, the semicolon). Because indentation doesn't matter in PHP, the `echo $i` will only echo once at the end of the loop, when `$i == 5`. You can view it better as the following:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    ;
    echo $i;
```